# How to change data for form in CreateView, GET method Django

Tags: django

I'm new in django and  trying create todo project and have some problems with categories. User shouldn'd see another user's categories in the createview for create this categories. User can create sub_category
How can i do this? Thanks for help and advice

my view:

```
class CategoryCreate(CreateView):
    model = TaskCategory
    template_name = 'category_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')
    fields = ['title', 'sub_category']
    context_object_name = 'categories'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.POST['sub_category'] != '':
            sub_category = TaskCategory.objects.get(pk=self.request.POST['sub_category'])
            form.instance.depth = sub_category.depth + 1
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CategoryCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

my model:

```
class TaskCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    depth = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    creater = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Why do you need to store the `depth` if you can just determine it when necessary?

Comment: i don't know. maybe it's be better but now have problem with category's list in category createview

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a `ModelForm` that takes an (optional) `user` parameter:

```
from django import forms


class TaskCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['sub_category'].queryset = TaskCategory.objects.filter(
                creater=user
            )

    class Meta:
        model = TaskCategory
        fields = ['title', 'sub_category']
```

then we can plug in that form with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class CategoryCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = TaskCategory
    template_name = 'category_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')
    form_class = TaskCategoryForm
    context_object_name = 'categories'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        sub_category = form.cleaned_data['sub_category']
        if sub_category is not None:
            form.instance.depth = sub_category.depth + 1
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This will also enforce that a user can *not* pick a super category that does not belong to them in the *POST* request, when they create a `TaskCategory`, so even if the POST request is "*fabricated*", the server will reject that.

the `sub_category` however looks more like a `sup_category` (super category, `sub_category` would mean the opposite).

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `CategoryCreateView`, instead of <s>`CategoryCreate`</s>.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin).

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.